# Run php code inside .html() jQuery function

Tags: php, html

I have a link:

```
<a id="btnExistReceiver" class="btn btn-app">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  <?= __('Existing Receiver') ?>                                                                       
</a>
```

I'd like to change the text inside, so I call the ".html()" function like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnExistReceiver").click(function() {
    $("#receiverForm").css("display", "block");
    $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-user'></i><?=  __( ' Existing R ') ?>");        
  });
});
```

The problem is that jQuery is commenting my PHP code. Here is the output:

```
<a id="btnExistReceiver" class="btn btn-app">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  <!--?= __('Existing Receiver') ?-->                                                                       
</a>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: This isn't a jQuery issue - it's a PHP/HTML one. Your PHP script is not being interpreted before rendering, so it's taken as HTML. The browser does not recognise the `<? ?>` tag, so changes it to a comment. You can see this happening in DOM inspector of this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qj0vv0rc/. To fix this problem, you need to run your JS code in a place where PHP code will be executed correctly. I assume it's currently in an external .js file?

Comment: instead of `<? ?>` have you tried using `<?php echo __( ' Existing R ') ?>` or does give the same output

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi Yes - put the JS code in a place where the PHP will be interpreted correctly, eg. *inside* a .php file

Comment: What is your file format .html or .php which?

Answer (score 1):

`PHP` within `JavaScript/jQuery` will not work.

So try,

```
<?php echo '<script>$(function() {
       $("#btnExistReceiver").click(function() {
          $("#receiverForm").css("display", "block");
          $(this).html("<i class=\'fa fa-user\'></i>'.__( ' Existing R ').'");        
          });
      });</script>';
?>
```

Comment: replace the script with this. Add the script tag inside the echo statement. Put it in php or html file. not in .js file

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the problem:
1- I put the php & jQuery codes in the same file ".ctp"
2- at the end of of ".ctp" file i put this code:

```
.
.
.        
</body>
        </html>


    <?php $this->start('script'); ?>

    <?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap-filestyle'); ?>
    <?= $this->Html->script('jquery-2.1.1.min.js'); ?>
    <?= $this->Html->script('jquery.form.min.js'); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#btnExistReceiver" ).click(function() {
            $( "#receiverForm" ).css( "display", "block" );

            $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-user'></i> <?php echo __( 'Inexistent Receiver') ?> ");

        });
    </script>

    <?php $this->end(); ?>
```

Thanks for all everyone who tried to help me